# How to pass arguments without concatenating in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

(I'm a PowerShell newbie, and finding it a *very* frustrating language)

I want to create a function - with arguments and a return value. Not rocket science? That's what I thought anyway. But PowerShell keeps concatenating my arguments - here's the MCVE version:

```
 function hello($a, $b) {
    Write-host "a is $a and b is $b"
 }

 hello("first", "second")
```

I was expecting this to produce the output:

```
 a is first and b is second
```

I wasn't expecting....

```
 a is first second and b is
```

along with the fact it is concatenating values in a way I don't expect, its also failing to flag up the argument which is consequently missing.

How can I pass arguments to a function? (!!!!OMG WTF????!!!)

Comment: It's a shell, and you pass parameters like you do on the command line. Same way you wouldn't use `grep('pattern', 'file1')` but `grep 'pattern' file1`. They match so you can use (advanced) functions, cmdlets and native binary commands all in much the same way.

Comment: Well, in the OP's defense you would use parens for function arguments in some shells. Python for instance. Having said that, I would suggest that the OP type this into a powershell prompt: ***Get-Help functions*** then pay specific attention to the Advanced Functions topics. If you are going to learn powershell you might as well go straight to doing it in the most Best Practices compliant way possible right off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the () from your call to the function

```
function hello($a, $b) {
    Write-host "a is $a and b is $b"
 }

 hello "first" "second"
or
hello -a "first" -b "second"
```